# Is $y=\frac{x^3+0.3x-7}{2x-1}$ Rational or Quotient Function?

Tags: functions, quadratics, graphing-functions, rational-functions

I understand this is an easy one question however, I just wanted to clarify which it would be considered as a rational function or a quotient function. I understand that a rational function has $y=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ as both polynomials while a quotient can be any two functions, I just want to clarify for the equation $y=\frac{x^3+0.3x-7}{2x-1}$.

Comment: A rational function is one formed by the fraction of two real polynomials (but the denominator can't be the zero polynomial), so...what do you think?

Comment: no? to be honest, I'm really unsure.

Comment: In order *not* to be a rational function, either the numerator is not a polynomial, or else the denominator is not a non-zero polynomial (or both are true).

Comment: Is $x^3 + 0.3x -7$ a polynomial?  Is $2x+1$?  ... Note.  It's not either/or  *every* polynomial is a rational function and *every* rational function is a quotient function. But it doesn't go the other way.

Comment: "I understand this is an easy one or the other question"  It's *NEVER* one or the other.  It's one but not the other or it is both.   It's like asking "Is it a reptile or is it animal?"  Well all reptiles are animals so it is *never* one or the other.  It is either neither, a non-reptile animal,  or both.  It is never a non-animal reptile.  Never.  No such thing.  .... The no such thing as a rational function that is *not* a quotient function.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your definitions, it seems like it should be both.